# Find out, why a question was deleted

Tags: support

Why was this question deleted? https://superuser.com/questions/603373/how-do-i-reverse-proxy-etherpad-lite-with-nginx-to-a-subdirectory And can you please undelete it? It sais there:

> deleted by community

And it sais:

> A moderator has deleted this post and it can't be undeleted"

Why? He didn't delete it himself and this question is still there for him

*see also [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260977/access-old-deleted-question/260979?noredirect=1#comment44961_260979)*

Answer (score 7):

From https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/133693

> Just to formally document the exact policies we have in place to
>   remove old abandoned / dead questions, [the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) will
>   delete questions in the following circumstances:
>
> **If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> **...or...**
>
> - it was closed and migrated to a different site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.
>
> **If the question is more than `365` days old, and ...**
>
> - has a score of 0 *or* a score of 1 with a deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has a viewcount <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.
>
> These checks are run every week across all sites.

Comment: OK, that explains it. But can you still undelete that question now please?

Comment: sure, it's done.